# When do we use sizeWithAttributes vs sizeThatFits?

Tags: ios

When I want to get a dynamic frame size for my `UILabels`, `SizeThatFits` seems dead easy and I'm wondering what is the advantage/disadvantage of using either one?

`SizeWithAttributes` seem complicated for what it does.

Answer (score 0):

They are methods on different classes. `sizeThatFits:` is for a `UIView` subclass while `sizeWithAttributes` is usable on an `NSString`.

The first tells you what size a view should be based on the subviews it has. The later is for knowing the dimensions of a given string, having a potentially advanced set of attributes (`NSAttributedString`).